# Google fit SessionAPI: SessionReadRequest is taking infinite time with no result

Tags: android, google-fit

I'm using Google Fit API to develop a fitness app.

I'm trying to use SessionApi with SessionReadRequest to read all the sessions in the past week created with my app. Here is the code I wrote:

```
/**
 *  Creates and executes a {@link SessionReadRequest} using {@link
 *  com.google.android.gms.fitness.SessionsClient} to get last week sessions data
 */
private Task<SessionReadResponse> readLastWeekSessions() {
    loader.smoothToShow();
    // Begin by creating the query.
    SessionReadRequest readRequest = readLastWeekFitnessSessions();

    // [START read_session]
    // Invoke the Sessions API to fetch the session with the query and wait for the result
    // of the read request. Note: Fitness.SessionsApi.readSession() requires the
    // ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission.
    return Fitness.getSessionsClient(getActivity(), GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(getContext()))
            .readSession(readRequest)
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<SessionReadResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<SessionReadResponse> task) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Session read completed");
                }
            })
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<SessionReadResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(SessionReadResponse sessionReadResponse) {
                    // Get a list of the sessions that match the criteria to check the result.
                    List<Session> sessions = sessionReadResponse.getSessions();
                    Log.i(TAG, "Session read was successful. Number of returned sessions is: "
                            + sessions.size());

                    for (Session session : sessions) {
                        // Process the session
                        dumpSession(session);

                        // Process the data sets for this session
                        List<DataSet> dataSets = sessionReadResponse.getDataSet(session);
                        for (DataSet dataSet : dataSets) {
                            dumpDataSet(dataSet);
                        }
                    }
                    loader.smoothToHide();
                }
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Failed to read sessions");
                }
            });
    // [END read_session]
}

/**
 * Returns a {@link SessionReadRequest} for all the data of the last week sessions
 */
private SessionReadRequest readLastWeekFitnessSessions() {
    Log.i(TAG, "Reading History API results for all the last week session");
    // [START build_read_session_request]
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    Date now = new Date();
    cal.setTime(now);
    long endTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();
    cal.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, -1);
    long startTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();

    // Build a session read request
    SessionReadRequest readRequest = new SessionReadRequest.Builder()
            .setTimeInterval(startTime, endTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .read(DataType.TYPE_CALORIES_EXPENDED)
            .read(DataType.TYPE_DISTANCE_DELTA)
            .read(DataType.TYPE_SPEED)
            .enableServerQueries()
            .build();
    // [END build_read_session_request]

    return readRequest;
}
```

It works when I have a small amount of data (only a few sessions). But if I want to read calories burned, total distance and average speed for the last month sessions (which is around 45 sessions I created for testing), it is loading infinitely (I waited more than 10 minutes which is unacceptable for such a request).

Is it a normal behavior? Am I supposed to destroy regularly the old sessions? Am I supposed the use aggregate data? (which I don't know how to do...)

EDIT: I guess that the problem comes from the fact that I'm getting a huge amount of datapoint for the speed which is not what I want. I want to get the average speed but don't know how to do...

Comment: I tried to time infinite time once..

Comment: ..and still haven't stopped :}

Comment: Come on please answer my question ^^

Comment: It happen with me but a little different. In my case I get 30 days ago, but doesn't have enableServerQueries(). The reason is the request contain  .read(DataType.TYPE_DISTANCE_CUMULATIVE).read(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_CADENCE). It never return result, even success or failed. Only I remove that field or change to 10 days, it works.

Comment: Did you find any suitable solution? We are facing the same problem.

Comment: Same problem here. We have used following: builder.read(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA)
 .read(DataType.TYPE_CALORIES_EXPENDED)
 .read(DataType.TYPE_DISTANCE_DELTA). It can work without issues for some time but for some of our users it just stops. We have released one version of an app without TYPE_DISTANCE_DELTA and it worked again for some time and it stopped again. We are not getting anything in callbacks, we have tried all four of them, onSuccess, onComplete ,onCanceled and onFailure.